# java code to create dynamic methods at runtime

Tags: dynamic, methods, creation

I have a dynamic list of variables for which I need to create getter and setter on the fly i.e. during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/).